# 'touch' events are being fired when the page loads. Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Tags: javascript

Context: I'm trying to implement a navigation-sidebar for mobile devices. In doing so, I added a touchstart event to an icon in my html so that when pressed it would fire a function that toggles the side-bar.

Problem: For some inexplicable reason, the event gets fired when the page is loaded!

Code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("bodyID").getElementsByClassName("fa-navicon");
    el[0].addEventListener("touchstart", alert("Hello"),false);
} );
```

To test whether the firing was caused my something else in my javascript I scrapped all of it and left only the shown code. This is literally the only javascript (other than a scrollTop plugin and the jQuery core) I have running on my test html page. No other event is attached to my icon either.

I feel like I'm attaching the event in the wrong manner - but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: The event does not get fired on load, *you're calling your handler instead of registering it*.

Comment: Somewhat related: What's the difference between click and touch events in phones. I tested my page on my phone and using an onmousedown="someFunction()" for the navigation icon still worked when I tapped it. Obviously, this means that I could just use that for the context I gave, but I'm also looking into doing other things with touch events so I need to figure out how to use them without having a ghost-fire.

Comment: Frederic: I thought .addEventListener was for registering an event. What would be the proper way to register an event then?

Comment: The proper way is to pass a function, as Erik Nijland demonstrates in his answer. You cannot pass `alert` itself since you wouldn't be able to specify an argument, so you have to write an anonymous function around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in a function as the second parameter of addEventListener:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("bodyID").getElementsByClassName("fa-navicon");
    el[0].addEventListener("touchstart", function() { alert("Hello") }, false);
});
```

Comment: I take it back, I was just passing functionName() as parameters all along. Teach a (clearly) noob: why isn't that valid (as in why do you need a an anonymous function if any function is a function object and therefore should be taken as parameters like with callbacks)?